# What's the best way for a github action to check whether only a particular directory was changed?

Tags: github, github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I want to skip my build process for GitHub PRs which only change files in a directory called `my-directory`.

If I do this:

```
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: my-filter
        with:
          filters: |
            workflows:
              - 'my-directory/**'
```

then steps.my-filter.outputs.workflows will return true for a change which affects at least one file in my-directory.

But what's the best way to check whether a change affected *only* files in this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return `true` if even one file outside of the `my-directory` has changed

```yaml
- uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
  id: my-filter
  with:
    filters: |
      workflows:
        - '!my-directory/**'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path-ignore` flag for `on:pull_request`  event.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'my-directory/**'
```

You can refer the official documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20push%20and%20pull_request%20events%2C%20you%20can%20configure%20a%20workflow%20to%20run%20based%20on%20what%20file%20paths%20are%20changed.%20Path%20filters%20are%20not%20evaluated%20for%20pushes%20of%20tags.).

Comment: But this will trigger when files both in- and outside of `my-directory` are modified at the same time; it can't tell that case apart from "nothing but flies in `my-directory`".